# Create a custom selected list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

Well im adding to database some records but i dont like the way i did and wanted to make something way easier for the user and better.

What i did was: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEfVZ.jpg

And what i want is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxqWR.jpg

Well i guess i know how to create the divs geting all the images from database and the horizontal scroll bar but what i dont know is when i select the image that id from image will appear on the input create by me.

Help needed.

Code from what i have:

```
<select name="id_artigo" id="attribute119">
<?php 
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']?>" ><?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_artigos = mysql_fetch_assoc($artigos));
?>
</select>

<div id="editimg"><p><img src="images/artigos/1.png" id="main" /></p></div>
```

Js:

```
$('#attribute119').change(function () {
  $('#main').attr('src', 'images/artigos/' + $('#attribute119 :selected').text() + '.png');
});
```

Comment: Seeing the image you posted, you will get multiple images from the database and when the user clicks on a particular image you want to get it's id??

Comment: yes thats it what i would like to, the real main was just selecting the image and then it automatically write the id at the database but i can do aswell and easier when press image it will put the id from image in a input box and its that one who goes to database

Comment: You can use the solution Shai posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you don't want it to look like a drop-down any more, replace the drop-down with a hidden field, which will hold the ID of the item they select:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="id_artigo" />
   ```

   (for testing you could use `type="text"` instead)
2. Give each of your images a `data-id-artigo` attribute:

   ```
   <img class="artigo_img" src="images/artigos/1.png" data-id-artigo="1">
   ```
3. When an image is clicked, update the hidden ID's value:

   ```
   $('.artigo_img').on('click', function() {
       var idArtigo = $(this).data('idArtigo'); // get the artigo ID from the `data-` attribute
       $('[name="id_artigo"]').val(idArtigo);   // update the value of the hidden field
   });
   ```

When the form is submitted, `id_artigo` will be equal to the selected item, just like before.

Comment: its working great theres just one mystake u write artigo_id and its id_artigo :p thanks ;)

Comment: @luckr Fixed, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery slideshow plugin like [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)  or [jssor](http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.html).
Just do a google search on "jQuery slideshow" or "jQuery carousel".

I recommend you to use jcarousel.

Anas

Comment: ok ill use it but my main was geting id from image when pressed prob a js will make it work but dont know.

Comment: you can put <img> tag into "<a> </a>", then the href attribute will contain an url for the action that you want to call

Answer (score 0):

I see now that you just want to select 1 image, this answer is for selecting multiple images.
(not tested, so there might be some errors)

```
    <style>

.img_holder
{
    height:100px;
    clear:both;
}

.floating_img
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.img_selected
{
  border:1px solid black;
}

</style>

<div class="img_holder">
<?php 

$img_id_arr = array();

do {  

$selected = true; //<--implement if they are selected

$selected_class = '';
if($selected)
    $img_id_arr[] = $row_artigos['id_artigo'];
    $selected_class = ' img_selected';
}

?>
<div class="floating_img<?php echo $selected_class; ?>" onclick="toggle_img(<?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']; ?>);"><img src="images/artigos/<?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']; ?>.png" id="main" /></div>
<?php
} while ($row_artigos = mysql_fetch_assoc($artigos));
?>
<input typ="hidden" id="my_selected_images" name="my_selected_images" value="<?php echo implode(';',$img_id_arr); ?>">

<script>

function toggle_img(img_id)
{
    var selected_imgs = $('#my_selected_images').value;
    var img_arr = selected_imgs.split(";");
    var found = false;
    var new_arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < img_arr.length; i++) { 
        if(img_id == img_arr[i])
        {
            found = true;
            //deselect img
        }
        else{
            //leave other item untouched
            new_arr.push(img_arr[i]);
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        new_arr.push(img_id);
        //select img
    }

    $('#my_selected_images').value = new_arr.join(';');

}
</script>
</div>
```